# Parse uint to positive long and have a 1 to 1 matching

Tags: c#, parsing, long-integer, uint64

Is there a safe way to parse **Uint** numbers into **positive** **Long** numbers and have a one to one matching between that uint and the long number??

Comment: if I receive a uint number and just cast it as (long)number, the result can also be negative, because in the long representation that sign bit is treated as part of the value

Comment: The sign is contained only in the MSB (highest bit). A 32 bit UINT (0 to ~4bn) is wholly represented in a 64 bit long, with 31 bits to spare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint i = 0;
long o = Convert.ToInt64(i);
```

or

```
uint i = 0;
long o = (long)i;
```

Comment: by doing Convert.ToInt64(i) the result could also be negative as a long, or can't it? Is there a difference between this way and just doing (long)i?

Comment: if you have an uint as input, you can't possibly get a negative int64, so just casting to long is good enough

Comment: 1011 (binary) as unsigned value is +11. convert this number to signed and the value you will get is -3. Isn't that correct?

Comment: see StuartLC comment above